# Unit testing inherited WinForms controls

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, moq, mvp

I've been working with Model-View-Presenter recently, and when I feel like I understand how to do things, I end up running into something new that I don't quite understand.

In my current case, I'm using a `PictureEdit` (which is basically a glorified `PictureBox` as part of DevExpress' WinForms controls), and while the `PictureEdit` is capable of zooming and scrolling, it's not entirely how I'd like it.

When you scroll with the mouse wheel, it causes the picture to pan up and down. I want this to instead zoom in and out by a specific amount. So I tried the following:

```
public class AlteredPictureEdit : PictureEdit
{
  protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.Delta > 0)
      this.Properties.ZoomPercent += 10;
    else
      this.Properties.ZoomPercent -= 10;
  }
}
```

So, this changes the behavior of the `PictureEdit` to zoom on mouse scroll instead of pan. But because I'm of the mind to make unit tests, I'd like to do so, but I can't figure out how.

Behaviorally, I would design my own presenter (the unit under test) and feed it a dependency injected view as a mock. Then I could use the mock to raise a `MouseWheel` event, then assert that the `ZoomPercent` value was increased or decreased.

By inheriting `PictureEdit`, I don't have a Presenter to unit test or a View to mock. I can't raise the `OnMouseWheel` event to test that `ZoomPercent` gets altered.

Is inheriting the `PictureEdit` the proper way to go about this, as shown above? And how do I unit test modifications that I've made to the class?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a test class which inherits from your own class, where you expose a public method to forward the call to the protected one, and use that for your test:

```
public class AlteredPictureEditTester : AlteredPictureEdit
{
    public void RaiseMouseWheelEvent(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
         OnMouseWheel(e);
    }
}
```

What I usually do in such a situations is actually to declare that class inside my test class to limit the scope.